# issue with INNER JOIN in MYSQL 6.3

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

im trying to join data from two tables like this:

```
Select portt.nameport, tool.weapen
From Portt 
Where  portt.toolsum - (    select count(*) 
                            From tool               
                            Group by nameport) >2
INNER JOIN tool on tool.nameport=portt.nameport;
```

but there is a 1064 error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN tool on tool.nameport=portt.nameport' at line 6
```

I dont get it why.

this code without the inner join works fine:

```
Select portt.nameport
From Portt 
Where  portt.toolsum - (    select count(*) 
                            From tool               
                            Group by nameport) >2;
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause has to come after the `JOIN` clause(s)

Comment: Please describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this query:

```
Select portt.nameport
From Portt 
Where  portt.toolsum - (select count(*) 
                        From tool               
                        Group by nameport
                       ) > 2;
```

You have a *scalar subquery*.  However, if could return more than one row, which would be an error.  I am guessing you want a correlated subquery here:

```
select p.nameport
from Portt p
where p.toolsum - (select count(*) 
                   from tool t          
                   where t.nameport = p.nameport
                  ) > 2;
```

Then, `JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.  The entire `FROM` clause needs to come before the where.  So I suspect you are trying to write:

```
select p.nameport
from Portt p join
     tool t
     on t.nameport = p.nameport
where p.toolsum - (select count(*) 
                   from tool t          
                   where t.nameport = p.nameport
                  ) > 2;
```